# How to convert nested dict to dataframe in pyspark.?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dict object like below.

```
data_dict={1016070000000: [[15245438, 1198], [53273831, 1198]], 10160700000201: [53273831, 1197]}
```

I want to convert it into dataframe as below.

```
   ID            cola       colb
1016070000000   15245438    1198
1016070000000   53273831    1198
10160700000201  53273831    1197
```

I tried to convert like this

```
spark.createDataFrame(data_dict.items()).show()
```

But its giving me error.
Can you please let me know how can I easily convert this dict into dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the nested dict into a nested list as below:

```
data_dict = {
    1016070000000: [[15245438, 1198], [53273831, 1198]],
    10160700000201: [53273831, 1197]
}
data = []
for k, v in data_dict.items():
    if isinstance(v[0], list):
        for row in v:
            data.append([k,row[0],row[1]])
    else:
        data.append([k,v[0],v[1]])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF('ID', 'cola', 'colb')
```